# Unable to load assets in custom .scss file in Angular Electron application

Tags: angular, electron, angular-library, electron-packager

I am packaging my angular application using electron packager. However, when opening the packaged application then the assets referenced from my custom created .scss files does not load correctly whilst my other assets (referenced directly from the libraries assets folder) loads correctly.

The angular project contains applications and libraries. It has the following structure

```bash
Root
  --> Projects
    --> Desktop
    --> Web
    --> Library-1
    --> Library-2
```

Library 1 has a fonts.scss file which **REFERENCES** the fonts:

*fonts are in library-1/src/assets/fonts*

[image]

*The assets is in the assets folder in the above picture*

One of the fonts I am trying to load from the fonts.scss file:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "OhBaby";
    src: url("/assets/fonts/OoohBaby-Regular.ttf");
}
```

*I have tried removing the / from the url path, but then the Web app doesn't work and the desktop application in developent doesnt work*

**Then I package the application with the following command:**

```bash
electron-packager ./dist/desktop MyAppName --overwrite --asar --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --icon=projects/desktop/src/assets/logo-accent.ico --prune=true --out=dist --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"MyAppName\""
```

How I reference the fonts file in a component:

```css
@import "../../../../../Library-1/src/styles/fonts.scss";
```

The desktop appplication with electron in development and my web application the fonts from the fonts.scss file works correctly, but not when I open the packaged desktop application.

The error that is produced for a font that is not working?

[image]

*The correct path should contain resources/app.asar/.../ in the url*

**Here is an asset reference that work:**

```bash
assets/images/brands/logo-android.svg
```

**Here are my angular.json where I ouput my assets:**

```
"assets": [
    "projects/desktop/src/favicon.ico",
    "projects/desktop/src/assets",
    {
        "glob": "**/*",
        "input": "./projects/library-1/src/assets",
        "output": "/assets/"
    }
],
"styles": [
    "projects/desktop/src/styles.scss"
],
```

**The assets are copied over correctly to the dist folder as seen in this image:**

files in dist/desktop/assets:
[image]

*I would like a solution that does not require me to move my fonts and other assets referenced in custom .scss files to the styles.scss file of library1.*

How can I tell the packager or electron to use the correct paths or how can I configure Angular to use the correct paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the / with a ^ when referencing an asset in a scss or css file.

e.g.

```
"^assets/fonts/OoohBaby-Regular.ttf"
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to how Electron packages the application and how SCSS interprets the paths for assets. SCSS doesn't understand the context of the Electron app, it merely processes the url as a string and leaves it as-is. This causes an issue when you try to package the application because the path context changes, the relative paths from the development server do not match up with the production structure.

The best way to handle this problem is to use relative paths in your SCSS file instead of absolute paths, and to ensure that the fonts are being bundled correctly with the Electron app.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "OhBaby";
    src: url("./assets/fonts/OoohBaby-Regular.ttf");
}
```

Ensure that these fonts are copied to the dist/desktop folder during the build process. This can be done by adding a section to the assets array in the angular.json file:

```
"assets": [
    "src/favicon.ico",
    "src/assets",
    { "glob": "**/*", "input": "projects/Library-1/src/assets/fonts", "output": "/assets/fonts" }
]
```

Make sure your "Electron's BrowserWindow's webPreferences object" is configured to use the correct preload script or to enable nodeIntegration:

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
        preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
        nodeIntegration: true,
        contextIsolation: false,
    },
});
```

In the file preload.js, you can then expose the required Electron API to your front-end.

```
const { contextBridge } = require('electron')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    'electron',
    {
        getAssetsPath: () => {
            return process.resourcesPath + '/app.asar/';
        }
    }
)
```

In your Angular code, you can then use this Electron API like:

```
const assetsPath = window.electron.getAssetsPath();
```

Using relative paths for font files in your SCSS should work as long as those fonts are being copied over correctly during the build process. If they're not being copied, you will need to find a way to include them in your build output...

Comment: Please check updated question. The assets are copied correctly. So from our answer I must use assetsPath  when refencing an asset?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `/assets` use just `assets/`. The first option implies that assets is in the root and it might not be there. That becomes relevant if you start messing with the `base-href` command line argument and I suspect it might be the cause of your problems.

---

Given your comment I suspect that perhaps you're not properly shipping the assets you've mentioned under your `angular.json` file.

Make sure that your "architect.build.options" include your scss files you're mentioning. There are two sections that are relevant:

```json
"assets": […],
"styles": […]
```

If you include your files under `assets` you have to reference the files through the relative `assets/` paths. This is handy if you're linking to the file itself from other places.

If you include it under your `styles` Angular will bundle, minify and inline into a `<style>` tag under the `index.html` that will be outputted and you cannot really use `<link>` tags as there'll be no `.css` file produced.

Comment: Tried to do that. Read the question.

Comment: Right, would you be able to share the angular.json file on a pastebin or something similar? I am suspecting that your `architect.build.options` might not be completely correct.

Comment: I habe updated the question with angular.json code. Please see above.